# How to estimate velocity of a point between two frame given 3d coordinates and angle between two segments?

Tags: geometry, physics, angle

I am working on gait data which has 3D coordinates of position for 15 joints per frame. I am trying to estimate velocity of ankle joint but I don't know how to find across frames. Given frame rate is 30 fps. Also I want to find angles between two segments let's say thigh and shank of same leg.

Comment: for speed compute mid point `p(i) = (p0(i)+p1(i))/2` of the bone you want for each frame `i` and then `vel(i) = (p(i)-p(i-1))*30.0;`  the angle change between frames is `acos(dot( p1(i)-p0(i) , p1(i-1)-p0(i-1) ));` however if you need signed one use atan2 for each consequent frames (i,i-1) separately and substract the results...

Comment: @Spektre Thank you. I tried using acos(dot(v1,v2)/norm(v1)*norm(v2)) but it doesn't have signed angles. But I think atan2 would give me better angles. For velocity the suggested method makes sense to me now.

Comment: hmm on second taught `atan2` will not work in 3D ... so you need to use the `acos(dot...` and decide the direction differently ... however in 3D its not that easy you first need to determine what does it mean positive and negative angle from that either exploit dot or cross product ... so you first need some additional info like some reference plane or rule ...

Comment: @Spektre I read some papers on Gait Analysis that takes out Sagittal, Coronal and Tranverse plane located at the centre of body. But to take out these planes I don't know where to start. I can take cross products to find plane normals but between which vectors I should take cross-product? Also regarding the speed calculation, do I have to take distance between two frames located at  distance of 30(since 30 fps) or just distance between two consecutive frames(like between 3rd and 4th frame)?

Comment: 1. you need to lock onto something. Onto what depends on what you are doing and what your coordinate system is ... for example you can use ground plane normal and right handed rule or up vector or whatever ... there is infinite possibilities and none are wrong or correct its just a matter of what you will considering as positive and negative angle. 2. two consequent frames as you got 30fps that means period (or update time) between frames is `1/30 [sec]` and `vel = delta_pos / delta_time = (p(i)-p(i-1))/(1/30.0) = (p(i)-p(i-1))*30.0;`

Comment: @Spektre thank you for the suggestion. The normal and plane method for floor is something I can try.